# Generating Google Documents from Google spreadsheet data source

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'm wondering what's the right way to create a Google document using a Google spreadsheet as a data source. I googled for a while and the only resource I found it is this explanation (http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/01/21/script-for-generating-google-documents-from-google-spreadsheet-data-source/), with the help of a Google App Script. Is there another (easy) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, no programming required. Check out the Google Docs add-ons, such as [DocumentMerge](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/documentmerge-by-pandadoc/bfcfcgpdofganbehkmbdofgmifdgbmdn), Smartsheet Merge, or [Ultradox](http://www.ultradox.com/).